# How to get the title image using Google Apps Script

Tags: forms, image, google-apps-script, google-classroom

Here's a picture of the image which is inserted into  `MultipleChoiceItem`, not an `ImageItem`. Now I want to get the image url through Google Apps Script. Below is my code.

How to get that?

```
   var form = FormApp.openById('1Y6u01jUdre9ykEEtgmI9eRVo7Clr1GadgdrLyFTVoH1NQ');
   var items = form.getItems();
   var title = items[0].getTitle();
```

[image: form screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unfortunately so far no endpoint has been implemented in Apps Script to get / set neither item images, nor choice images

However, Feature requests have already been filed for both (see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/70078369) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/36765070)).

I recommend you to "star" those feature requests to increase visibility and hope for prompt implementation.